# CNN model giving same output for all classes in a multi class image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

```
#imported libraries
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory(r'C:\Users\mishr\OneDrive\Desktop\jj',
                                          target_size=(150,150),
                                          batch_size = 32, class_mode='categorical')

test_dataset = test.flow_from_directory(r"C:\Users\mishr\Downloads\SoML_Hackathon\SoML-50\test_data",
                                          target_size=(150,150),
                                          batch_size =32, class_mode='categorical')


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)), MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'), MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    #Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_dataset,
         steps_per_epoch = 250,
         epochs = 10,
         validation_data = test_dataset
       
         )

def predictImage(filename):
    img1 = image.load_img(filename,target_size=(150,150))
    
    plt.imshow(img1)
 
    Y = image.img_to_array(img1)
    
    X = np.expand_dims(Y,axis=0)
    val = model.predict(X)
    print(val)
```

This is the code that I used. I am a beginner in machine learning , so I am not able to identify where this went wrong. Whatever image I want to predict, it outputs the same answer [0,1,0] for all the images.

Comment: What is the loss and accuracy of the model?

Comment: loss: 2.5598 - accuracy: 0.2884 - val_loss: 1.2560 - val_accuracy: 0.3333

Comment: With a `val_accuracy` of 33% for 3 classes your model is making random guesses. The loss also shows that it is not confident at all with each prediction.

Comment: Actually right now I used very little data to train it.. I am still working on organizing my dataset..So if I increase my dataset , then do u think it  should run ok or apart from that are there any inherent errors in the code

Comment: Maybe you are getting the same prediction because of class imbalance. Meaning, you have one majority class in your dataset and the other two are minorities, so your model is only learning one class. Adding more data and data augmentation might help. If you don't have data then use Transfer Learning.